# How to fill a field depending on another control field in Orbeon

Tags: field, orbeon

How can I have a field `control2` which depends on another field `control1`? That is, when I fill `control1`, `control2` gets filled with the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 'control2' to have the same value as 'control1', you should go to the control settings of 'control2' under the Formulas tab and write the following in the Calculated Value field:

```
$control1
```

Take a look at [this section of the wiki for further information](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/formulas-examples.html#simple-calculated-values)

Comment: Great! Unfortunately I cannot retract my flag, but I'll leave this comment for reviewers. This is not "low quality" any more.

Comment: No worries. I'm fairly new to this whole thing, but I can see why just posting a link is not as useful. Especially if the link dies in the future.

Comment: I edited the question for grammar and clarity and modded it up.